# How should I randomly generate a fixed length String variable directly using UTF8 or UTF16?

Tags: java, string, hash, utf-8, salt

So this is my code, it basically generate a salt for encryption.
To generate random characters, I simply used a pre-declared String variable that holds all the characters so the code generate the String output based on the pre-declared variable

However I think that the outcome is probably not as random if I use a much larget set of keys such as UTF8 or 16 to generate the salt.

```
static final String keychain = "0123456789qwertyuioasdfghjklzxcvbnm,.+_=-][}{;:></?'|!@#$%^&*()坢坣坥坧坨坩坪坫坬坭坮" ;
static SecureRandom randomValue = new SecureRandom();


public static String GetRandomSalt(){


    StringBuilder constructsalt = new StringBuilder(16);
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i ++){
        constructsalt.append(keychain.charAt(randomValue.nextInt(keychain.length())));
    }

    System.out.println(constructsalt.toString());
    return constructsalt.toString();


}
```

So would it be possible to directly generate a random fixed length String using the UTF8/16 keyset in reference to the code above?

Comment: By the way, while I am no security expert, I expect [`UUID.randomUUID`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID()) would suffice as a salt.

Comment: @BasilBourque 3x No. [1] That is exactly 128 bits worth, and the need for a salt may or may not match up with this. What if the salt needs to be 192, or 96? [2] It's not completely random, which is bad news for crypto. The point of a salt is to inject 128 bits worth of entropy. UUIDs inject less than that. [3] UUIDs are often rendered as strings and who knows how boneheaded crypto libraries treat those. They certainly will not be capable of turning a UUID-formatted string into the underlying 128 bits, that's for sure. So, this is a horrible idea. Do not do this in crypto.

Comment: So I essentially just make it a lot longer?

Comment: What's the problem? Your code prints out a string with characters randomly selected from your source string. This is what you claim you wanted.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you question. Do you want a numeric salt? why not using a random number and use base64 to get values? Random string is never random (00 is seldom used, also control character set C0 and C1, not all character are represented, and some requires a precise sequences (e.g. combining characters, surrogates in utf-16). UTF-16 is not well defined (big or little endian), utf-8 has various redundant bits (to synchronize errors).

Answer (score 2):

> However I think that the outcome is probably not as random if I use a much larget set of keys such as UTF8 or 16 to generate the salt.

You appear to be confused.

Encryption is entirely done on **bytes**. Not characters. Bytes are numbers, and they go from 0 to 255. That's all there is.

You can, however, turn characters into bytes, if you want. There is no one set way to do this; US-ASCII is one way (and only defines 96 characters, mapping to range 32-127). UTF-8 is another. Most encodings have the property that it **cannot** result in every imaginable possible byte sequence; only a subset of them. That's bad news for crypto, so avoid using strings. Period. (There are sequences of bytes that will **never** be the result of converting a string to bytes, for almost all encodings).

The fact that `getRandomSalt` returns a String?

You messed that up. That's wrong. It should be returning `byte[]`.

Lots of crypto tools, APIs, and tutorials *do* appear to use strings. This has two, separate, and both equally silly, origins:

### Misunderstanding of charsets

A whole bunch of programming languages casually blur the distinction between a string and a sack of bytes, and can't tell the difference between `"Hello"` and `[0,72, 101, 108, 108, 111]`. This is a very silly idea - there are more characters than just what english tends to use, and the whole unicode symbol set doesn't fit in that 0-255 range; after all, there are *way* more than 256 unique characters.

Java, fortunately, is not such a silly language. byte[] and String are not interchangible, and thus, make that method return a `byte[]`.

### Easier to transit to human eyeballs

It's a lot easier to read Hello than to read 0, 72, 101, 108, 108, 111. But keeping things as strings is, best-case, confusing, and worst-case, **seriously reduces** the ability of your keys and salts to express randomness. **This is bad**.

Hence, this replaces **all** your code you pasted in your question and is vastly superior:

```
public byte[] getRandomSalt() {
    byte[] salt = new byte[16];
    random.nextBytes(salt);
    return salt;
}
```

Comment: but somehow when using the Random or secureRandom class to generate a salt (byte[]) the value is always the same

Comment: @JVAV_master: The value is **not** always the same.